# Linq to SQL Row Not Found or Changed Exception on Insert Operation Ajax Postback in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I have an MVC3 View that's posting back a set of input values via Ajax to my controller. My controller is then creating a new FieldTripRoute object on my context and attempting to insert it into the database.

I just can't figure out what's going on. I've triple checked my Designer schema and my DB schema and they match perfectly. So it can't be the normal issue of a column not existing or being nullable in one area but not another. However, I keep receiving a "Row Not Found or Changed" exception every time I attempt to submit changes.

The stack trace on the exception looks like this:

```
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at ManageMAT.Controllers.FieldTripController.RouteAdd(Int32 id, FormCollection collection)
```

This is the code that's being called to add the new Route object from the Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RouteAdd(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            FieldTrip trip = context.FieldTrips.Single(ft => ft.ID == id);

            if (trip == null) return Json(new { success = false, message = "Field trip not found." }); ;

            try
            {

                FieldTripRoute tripRoute = new FieldTripRoute();

                tripRoute.FieldTripID = trip.ID;                
                tripRoute.Date = DateTime.Parse(collection["Date"]);
                tripRoute.ArrivalTime = DateTime.Parse(collection["ArrivalTime"] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                tripRoute.DepartureTime = DateTime.Parse(collection["DepartureTime"] + " " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                tripRoute.Destination = collection["Destination"];
                tripRoute.PickupLocation = collection["PickupLocation"];
                tripRoute.RouteID = Convert.ToInt32(collection["RouteID"]);           

                context.FieldTripRoutes.InsertOnSubmit(tripRoute);
                context.SubmitChanges();

                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success!" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

And here is my Designer and DB Table Columns:

[image: Designer and DB Table Columns]

I've also attempted to view the SQL this is outputting in both the logging available on the context object and in SQL Profiler, but it seems to be failing before it's even hitting the Database server.

Edit: Forgot to add one other thing, when I'm initially creating the new FieldTripRoute object at the beginning of the Add action I noticed that it's not retrieving the correct ID from the database identity series. Perhaps this is related?

I've also tried setting the Update Check on every field in the designer to Never just to see if it was some kind of bizarre concurrency collision going on, but I am still receiving the same error.

I'm really at a loss for what could be causing this issue. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is thrown every time the row is not inserted for whatever reason. For DML statements Linq to SQL checks the number of modified rows. SQL Server returns this count. It is checked to be one.

The big question is why is the count zero and yet no error message is being sent by SQL Server. Start SQL Server profiler and post the SQL that L2S generates. Run the SQL manually and see what happens. Does a row get inserted? Does its identity value get returned?

Edit: More debugging ahead: Shut down SQL server just before you to the SubmitChanges to make sure that the database is not being hit. Lets make sure to cut this branch off the search tree.

Next, step into the Linq to SQL source code to see whats up. If you have R# this is easy: Press ctrl-shift-t, search ChangeProcessor, click and navigate to the "sources from symbol files". Find the function SubmitChanges and put a breakpoint in there. If you don't have R#, you need to dig out some tutorial on the web for this (it's going to take about 5min).

Step through the source to find why the exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah that's another thing I forgot to mention, I checked the ID value after creating a new object and I'm getting a 0 back. The correct ID should be 92 I believe based on the current table identity values.

Also, I've tried to check the SQL but it's throwing the exception before even generating it. As far as I can tell somewhere something inside of Linq is throwing it before it even hits the DB. When I run profiler on the DB it doesn't even touch it before throwing the exception.

Comment: The ID value should update only on SubmitChanges, btw. This is normal. Maybe you did not configure the ID fields update mode to "auto-sync" in L2S?

Comment: The ID column in my designer has Auto-Sync set to OnInsert. So that makes sense.

Comment: I have no idea then (except that you try to disconnect the SQL database - my feeling is that the database is being used).

Comment: After digging into it a bit it looks like the issue may not be with the FieldTripRoute, but the referenced Field Trip object. The SQL that's being generated by Linq to update that object is coming out as `UPDATE [dbo].[FieldTrip]
SET [ModifiedUser] = @p0, [ModifiedDate] = @p1
WHERE 0 = 1`, however the fields are matched in the designer so I'm going to try resynching all of the tables to see if that works.

Comment: That is a strange query! I recomment you delete the two tables from the designer and recreated them. It seems their definition is deeply ... disturbed.

Comment: That was the Solution! Apparently the FieldTrip table in the designer was somehow out of sync even though all columns matched